Error trying to connect hive to remote url
I am trying to connect hive to unity catalog (outside Databricks) instead of mysql or derby.
this is hive-site.xml
<property>
    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
    <value>http://localhost:8080/api/2.1/unity-catalog</value>
 </property>

but it gives this error:
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

when running
show databases;

Any ideas? and sorry if I am asking badly.
